# How to convert Unicode characters to ANSI using AutoIt?

Tags: java, autoit

I am reading a Java properties file with AutoIt that includes some unicode characters in `\u0xxx` format.

How can I convert them to ANSI with AutoIt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks goes to all that helped: [How to convert Unicode characters to ANSI using AutoIt?](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/155228-how-to-convert-unicode-characters-to-ansi-using-autoit/)

This is the solution:

```
#include <WinAPI.au3>

Local $str = "My name is \u0393\u03A1\u0397"
Local $utfStr = Execute("'" & StringRegExpReplace($str, "(\\u([[:xdigit:]]{4}))","' & ChrW(0x$2) & '") & "'")
Local $ansiStr = _WinAPI_WideCharToMultiByte($utfStr)
MsgBox(64,"Unicode2Ansi", $utfStr & @CRLF & $ansiStr)

Exit
```